# Handle nginx upload request based on request header

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location

nginx by default supports uploading with client_body_in_file_only on; which sends only the file path to the backend. There is the nginx upload module (https://github.com/vkholodkov/nginx-upload-module) which supports multipart/formdata uploading.

Now i want to have one location for instance /photo/upload/ which handles both kind of uploads as mentioned above. It should be based on a request header supplied by the user. for instance user request header should contain something like X-UPLOADTYPE multiprt or X-UPLOADTYPE clientbody and based on this header nginx should handle the request.

I am not sure how should i proceed with this so and help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure why Nginx wouldn't support `multipart/formdata`, I'm using it myself to upload stuff to my website and use PHP to save metadata to the DB (and move the files to the destination).

Comment: I want to achieve performance, and this is done by telling nginx to handle the upload and not forward it to the backend(php) chunks by chunks. The ideal solution is to let nginx completely handle the upload and when its done it simply sends a signal to the php backend with the filepath only!

Comment: So, you want to achieve performance. Does that mean you are not achieving performance at this point?

Comment: Please read my above comment again to understand what the problem is. PHP shouldbent be used for long running processes such as uploading a big file.